# After effects color leak

Tags: video, video-processing, after-effects, post-processing

I'm having a problem with after effects. Basically there is two videos, one black and white, other one is colored, the goal is to do some objects colored, while others stays b/w. Did that using roto brush tool, but after rendering video ( tried almost all different reder settings / options ) random color spots appear.

Screenshot:

[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFwTO.jpg)

As you can see, on the right image there is color spot next to his right arm, while in composition view everything is fine.

And if there is a better way to achieve what im doing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Found to ways to fix this problem:

1) Download Loseless codecs and render without compression. You can always compress later using ffmpeg (recommended) or simmilar software

OR

2) Add another layer and make it fully black and white. It will recalculate leaks twice and will be fixed.